# Best way for customerrors asp.net MVC images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I am using Asp.Net MVC for my web page. And I am trying to show custom error messages to my visitors of my web page so that I added

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error" >
    </customErrors>
```

to my web.config.

I have an Error controller with an Index action that fired when an exception occurred in my web page.

But when i request an image or a javascript file that doesn't on server my custom error also hit for this type of requests and my custom error page arrived from server.

I think this is not a good solution for errors. Because browser waiting an image but response is a web page.

- Question 1 - I want to disable custom errors for specific file types but i don't know how to do that.
- Question 2 - Also If there is an error like 404,500 etc. I want to see a response code same with error.

But with custom errors response code is 302. I expect to see the real error code.

I found a solution for my first question, but i dont know that it is the best practice
My Images are in Images folder so I create a specific configuration for my Images folder.

I added this lines to my web.config

```
   <location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

- Question 3 - Is it a good solution?

Comment: so what should be served if the image is not found !?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HttpModule` that subscribes to the `Error` event. Check the StatusCode and if its 404 (not found) check for what file was requested. If its a image, clear the Exception and set the StatusCode to something else than 404 and you won't hit the customError page.

About maintaining the original statuscode, you can save that in your `HttpModule` as well and setting it back in your Error controller.